# How to Remove Delay on Css3 Slide out transition which uses max-height transition

Tags: css-transitions

I'm having an issue with a transition I'm using to slide a panel in and out.

Please take a look at the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/uvejuj/1/

Notice that when i click the toggle button the first time the transition occurs immediately.

However if i click the button again to close then the transition delays the amount of time of the transition before it executes.

What is causing the delay on close out and how can i get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's because you're animating between `0` and `1000px` `max-height`, but your content is only about `120px` high. The delay is the animation happening on the 880 pixels you can't see.

Either set `max-height` to the known `height` of your content (if you know it - example: http://jsbin.com/onihik/1/) or try a different method. Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486082/2619379

Comment: Great explanation of why the delay happens!

Comment: The other answer gives a perfect solution where there was otherwise none, but this answer is still great as it explains the _why_ which many of us still want to know.

Answer (score 44):

[Fixed JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ladide/edit?html,css,output)

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the actual answer - perfect solution. While @Jay Rafferty's solution makes perfect sense, this is the technical solution.

Comment: Works perfect with chrome. Thanks!

Comment: I've said it on the other (exact same) answer you provided: This answer needs an explanation. It's upvoted quite a bit, but it doesn't even work properly. The only effect I'm seeing, is that the retracting transition is only 0.5s vs the expanding transition that's 1s, and the function being used is basically an extreme `ease-out`. So basically, you're just contracting those 1000px of max height really quickly, and slowing down in the end, so the final bit looks somewhat like a regular `ease-in-out`. This is not a fix, this is a workaround, and I'd hardly call it a good one.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in my case by using a normal transition for opening (from `max-height: 0px` to `max-height: 500px`) BUT by using an animation when closing, starting from `max-height: 50vh`.

This way, the delay is not from shrinking from `5000px` to the actual height of your content.
The only delay that can appear now is if your content is less than `50%` of your screen height, but that works butter-smooth in my cases.

Here's my magic (scss format):

```
.slide-open{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:not(.open){
    animation-name: shrink;
    animation-duration: .3s;
  }
  &.open{
    max-height: 5000px;
    transition: max-height .9s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% { max-height: 50vh; }
  100% { max-height: 0; }
}
```