# Animation waits before performing

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to animate an elements height using css. The way I'm doing it is, I added a touch event to an element. The function adds a `className` to the element that's supposed to hide, i.e. get a height of 0.

The problem is, when the element gets clicked, the `div` that's supposed get a height of 0 pauses a second then gets the desired height. It seems like the longer the animation duration is, the long it waits before it animates.

Here's the relevant code:

```
transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g9mvdxs1/)

```js
var heading = document.getElementById('heading'),
  body = document.getElementById('body');

heading.addEventListener('click', hide);
body.addEventListener('transitionend', hideCallback);

function hide() {
  body.className = 'hide';
}

function hideCallback(e) {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
#buttonIcon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
#buttonLabel {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
#heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#body {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#body.hide {
  transition: max-height 2s ease-in-out;
  max-height: 0;
}
#innerBody {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttonContainer"><span id="buttonIcon">My</span><span id="buttonLabel">self</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="heading">Press Me</div>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="innerBody"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Replied also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087098/how-to-remove-delay-on-css3-slide-out-transition-which-uses-max-height-transitio?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're animating `max-height` and not `height`. Animating `max-height` is a trick that's used for animating the height of elements with an unknown height. You state a very large `max-height`, and as long as the unknown height is less than the max-height, it works. The only downside is that since your animating something that is bigger than your actual height, it will have a delay. In this case your `max-height` is 500px, and the height (including padding) is only 220px, which means that more than have the time (~1.1sec) is just reducing the max-height to 220px, and when it gets there, the visual starts to animate.

If, like this example, you know the actual height of the element (220 = padding 10 + innerBody height 200), you can animate the exact height.

If you don't know the height beforehand, try to lower `max-height` estimates and use an easing that starts fast, like `ease-out` or use javascript to set the start and end height.

Known `height: 220px` (watch in **full screen**):

```js
var heading = document.getElementById('heading'),
  body = document.getElementById('body');

heading.addEventListener('click', hide);
body.addEventListener('transitionend', hideCallback);

function hide() {
  body.className = 'hide';
}

function hideCallback(e) {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
#buttonIcon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
#buttonLabel {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
#heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#body {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#body.hide {
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
}
#innerBody {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttonContainer"><span id="buttonIcon">My</span><span id="buttonLabel">self</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="heading">Press Me</div>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="innerBody"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unknown height with javascript - set the actual height before the start of the animation, wait for next frame, and change it to 0 (watch in **full screen**):

```js
var heading = document.getElementById('heading'),
  body = document.getElementById('body');

heading.addEventListener('click', hide);
body.addEventListener('transitionend', hideCallback);

function hide() {
  body.style.height = body.scrollHeight + 'px'; /** sample actual height, and set it on element **/
  requestAnimationFrame(function() { // wait for next frame
    body.style.height = 0; // change height to 0
  });
}

function hideCallback(e) {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 470px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
}
#buttonContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}
#buttonIcon {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
#buttonLabel {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
#heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#body {
  color: #000;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: height 2s ease-in-out;
}

#innerBody {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttonContainer"><span id="buttonIcon">My</span><span id="buttonLabel">self</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="heading">Press Me</div>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="innerBody"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! The more you know. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your initial `max-height` is set to 500px but the actual height is much less. In the transition, that 500px is gradually decreased towards 0. At first that has no visual effect, until the max-height becomes smaller then the actual height. this produces the "delay" you are seeing.

You should either transition the actual `height` property to 0 (but that only works if the initial height is set as well, to 200px in your case). Or you could look into transitioning a `transform: scaleY(0)`, which has the added benefit of being much cheaper and giving a much smoother animation. (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason I can't use `scaleY(200)` is for two reasons. 1 - That scales things down to the middle, not to the top or bottom. 2 - It doesn't remove the space.

Comment: You can set a `transform-origin`, but that won't change the fact that the space remains. That is also the reason why it is so much cheaper btw. Anyway, fixed heights it is then. @OriDrori answer probably has the code you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

try some other CSS `transition-timing-function` like `linear` or `ease-out`.

As per [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp),

> ease-in-out   Specifies a transition effect with a slow start and end (equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42,0,0.58,1))

Comment: This doesn't solve her issue. There's still a delay before onset of the animation.

Comment: Consider testing out the code before posting an answer! @timolawl is correct!